# Express as product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory

Express $f=(1  3  2  5)(1  4  3)(2  5  1)$ as product of disjoint cycles.

In one of my books the answer is $(1 2)(3 4 5)$. I have seen many examples but the the process is confusing. Hopefully someone here can help me.

Comment: It really depends on whether you read cycles from left to right, or from right to left. But in both cases, your book is wrong.

Comment: I think that too. Would you please explain?

Comment: There are several conventions on how you read such permutations. Each cycle from left to right or backwards and the left cycle last if you think of $f$ as mapping with circles between the cycles, otherwise the left cycle first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read each cycle from left to right and the left one first, I get
$$f=(12)(354)$$
What I've done is to look what happens with $1$ in the left cycle. We see there $1\mapsto 3$. Now we have to look what happens with $3$ in the middle cycle. It's just $3\mapsto 1$ and in the last cycle we see $1\mapsto 2$. Now we have to ask, what happens with $2$. That's $2\mapsto 5\mapsto 5\mapsto 1$. Note that the cycle in the middle doesn't act on $2$ and $5$. They are fix. We thus saw $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1$, hence we have a cycle $(12)$.

For the sake of completeness:
\begin{align}
&3\mapsto 2\mapsto 2\mapsto 5\\
&5\mapsto 1\mapsto 4\mapsto 4\\
&4\mapsto 4\mapsto 3\mapsto 3 
\end{align}
We can now claim $f=(12)(354)$.